# MIPS Assembly Sorting an Array

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to implement the following bubble sort algorithm in MIPS:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            if (arr[j+1] < arr[j])
            {
                // swap temp and arr[i]
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
```

And this is what I have for my MIPS code. Keep in mind I am new to assembly. It isn't working but I am not sure where I am going wrong. We have to use MARS MIPS simulator so I am not getting the best details about what is going wrong.

```
.data
array: .word 14, 12, 13, 5, 9, 11, 3, 6, 7, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1, 31, 51, 41, 71, 21, 61, 91, 81
space: .asciiz " "

.text
.globl main

main: 
la $a0, array           # loads a0 with address of array        
li $t0, 0               # to = 0, iterator_i (outer loop)
li $t1, 0               # t1 = 0, iterator_j (inner loop)
addi $t2, 1, -22        # store n-1 in t2 for outer loop
sub $t3, $t2, $t0       # store n-1-i in t3 for inner loop

outerLoop:
blt $t2, $t0, exit      # if i > n-1, exit
addi $t0, $t0, 1        # i++
li $t1, 0               # sets j = 0 after every outer loop iteration
j innerLoop

innerLoop:
blt $t3, $t1, outerLoop # go to outerLoop if n-1-i < j
addi $t4, $t0, 1        # ignore the increment of i
j ifStatement

ifStatement:
addi $t5, $t1, 4        # t5 = j + 1, which goes to next word
lw $a1, $t1($a0)        # a1 = a[j]
lw $a2, $t5($a0)        # a2 = a[j+1]
blt $a1, $a2, innerLoop # if a[j] < a[j+1] exit if statement
j swap

swap:
lw $t6, $a1             # tmp = a[j]
sw $a2, $a1             # a[j] = a[j+1]
sw $a1, $t6             # a[j+1] = tmp
j ifStatement

exit:
nop
```

Comment: I went over to godbolt, put in your code for a mips compiler, and got a result.  You can compare your assembly vs what it outputs and debug from there.  https://godbolt.org/z/USmp81

Comment: what's wrong about MARS? It's debugger is usable, not the most luxurious one, but shouldn't stop you...